# Write code to test if a point is in circles

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a list of circles, I need to find if a point is in a circle which will return "Large" if it in a circle or "Small" if not! For most of the points given my code was right but i don't know why for some cases, it return "Large" instead of "Small". Thank you!

```
list1 = {}
list2 = []
step = 0
number_of_circles = int(input())
for i in range(number_of_circles):
    x,y,z = map(float,(input().split()))
    list1[i] = [x+z,x-z,y+z,y-z]
number_of_points = int(input())
for i in range(number_of_points):
    m,k = map(float,input().split())
    if any(j[1] <= m <= j[0] and j[3] <= k <= j[2] for j in list1.values()):
        list2.append("Large")
    else:
        list2.append("Small")     
print("\n".join(list2))
```

Edited: So x,y,z which x,y is the center of the circles and z is the radius of the circles. My plan was to check if the given point is in the circles by check the x-coordinate and y-coordinate of the given point(which is "m" and "k" in my code) is in range of the circle by finding the range of the circle (taking the center minus the radius and plus the radius to find the range)

Comment: You don't have a collection of circles; you have a collection of *bounding boxes* that circumscribed a circle. You are incorrectly marking points that exist outside a circle but lie within (a corner of) a bounding box as in a circle.

Comment: Would you care to explain what your logic is supposed to be?

Comment: I just edited it

Comment: Your explanation is a bit hand-wavy: `"by finding the range of the circle"`. Anyway, as has been stated, your actual code is checking the input points against *bounding boxes*.

Comment: a circle is defined by a center and a radius. a point is inside a circle if its distance to the circle center is lower than the radius

Answer (score 2):

given a list of circles `circles = [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [x3,y3,z3]]` where x,y is the center and z is the radius.

and given a point `point = [x,y]`

just iterate over the circles and check that the distance to the center is lower than the radius.

You can avoid the square root by comparing the squares directly

```
def is_inside_a_circle(point, circles):
    for circle in circles:
        if (point[0]-circle[0])**2 + (point[1]-circle[1])**2 < circle[2]**2:
            return True
    return False
```

Then you can call the function and print Small or Large depending if the point is inside a circle or not

```
print("Large" if is_inside_a_circle(point, circles) else "Small")
```

Note that having the radius defined as z is very confusing.

Ideally create a class Circle which has a Center and Radius attributes and can have methods like `is_point_inside(self, point)` where you implement this logic.

Then instead of a list of lists, you will have a list of circle instances.